# Always hide cursor in Xfce 4.8 with Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, mouse, debian, xserver, xfce

I would like to hide my cursor always. I have only SSH access to the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with **unclutter**, is a small program that does just that.

- http://ftp.x.org/contrib/utilities/unclutter-8.README
- http://ftp.x.org/contrib/utilities/unclutter-8.tar.Z

It's present on the repositories of various distributions, for example on Arch Linux you can install it with:

```
pacman -S unclutter
```

Then you can start it by adding an entry for it on **Settings » Session and Startup » Applications Autostart** or (preferred method) by adding it to your `.xinitrc` file like this:

```
run unclutter
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this information! Thats exactly what i searched for!

Comment: `unclutter -idle 0 -jitter 2000` works for always hiding.

Comment: Also works on `Debian 10 + Xfce-4.6`.
Just only run `unclutter`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: obsolete now

My solution was to download: [A transparent cursor theme](http://gpl.matrix-vision.com/mvblx-sources/GPL/xcursor-transparent-theme/) and do:

```
./configure
cd cursors
make install-data-local DESTDIR=/home/user/.icons/default CURSOR_DIR=/cursors
chown -R user:user /home/user/.icons
```